# How to tell Apache to not overwrite a LocationMatch and "Require all denied"?

Tags: apache-2.4, apache2

I have the following directive set in `security.conf` to stop apache from serving any hidden files or dirs.

```
<LocationMatch ^(.*/)\..*>
    Require all denied
</LocationMatch>
```

In `000-default.conf` is the follwoing directive to protect the whole site via HTTP auth.

```
<Location />
    AuthUserFile /var/www/site/.htpasswd
    AuthName "Restricted Area"
    AuthType Basic
    Require valid-user
</Location>
```

Now when I'm logged in `<LocationMatch ^(.*/)\..*>` gets completely ignored. I tried it with:

```
<Location />
    ...
    Satisfy all
</Location>
```

.. no success :(

Comment: You might want to read up on [how directives and configuration sections are merged](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/sections.html#merging) by apache httpd

Comment: You are also trying combinations of Apache v2.2 (`Satisfy`) and v2.4 directives (`require all denied`). This is never a good idea. Update all the directives the the v2.4 ones and comment out the loading of mod_access_compat

Answer (score 3):

The problem really comes from, as @HBruijn points out, the way Apache merges the different sections and the difficulties that come from mixing file system based restrictions (such as `<Directory>` and `<Files>`) and URI path based ones (such as `<Location>`. It is safer, and easier, to use either and not both because of the way one can completely override the other.

So for example, in Apache v2.4 if you use `Directory` instead of `Location` in your above example and use `FilesMatch` to deny access to the files with a leading `.`, it should work. But if you try to use Location for both it wont.

Example:

```
<FilesMatch "^\..+$">
  require all denied
</FilesMatch>

<Directory /path/to/your/docroot>
  AuthUserFile /var/www/site/.htpasswd
  AuthName "Restricted Area"
  AuthType Basic
  Require valid-user
</Directory>
```

Note in the page @HBruijn linked there is actually a warning not to try to use `<Location>` blocks to restrict access to files on the files system under the **What to use When** section.